# use Save File Dialog in Asp.net to save directly in Client PC

Tags: c#, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [save as dialog in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227032/save-as-dialog-in-asp-net)

i need to use SaveFileDialog in asp.net to save TextFile in Client PC.
how can i do that ?
i don't want to upload to server then download. i need to save in Client Pc Directly
. Is there an alternative Control in asp.net

Comment: Could someone explain the downvote here? It appears the OP is not familiar with the framework; in which case, this would be a perfectly reasonable question for someone to ask.

Answer (score 2):

You could use Silverlight or Flash. However, in a web browser, it is NOT possible to run C#/ASP.NET code directly on the client. Keep in mind that your ASP.NET code runs on the server, not the client. The only way to save a file to the client PC would be to either use Silverlight/Flash (which both have equivalent controls), or require the client to download the file from the server.